# ora2pg "number of rows extracted" vs "Scanning table"

Tags: ora2pg

In the debug logs for ora2pg, I see this:

```
[2023-04-14 19:51:57] DEBUG: number of rows 138136 extracted from table MY_TABLE
```

and also this

```
[2023-04-14 19:51:03] [3] Scanning table MY_TABLE (137999 rows)...
```

What is the difference between these two? The first line "number of rows" is indeed the correct number of lines in the Oracle table. But what is the second number? And why is it different?

I ask because after the table is migrated, the correct 138136 rows are indeed migrated to postgres.

In the validation I see this, which makes me happy:

```
OK, Oracle and PostgreSQL have the same number of rows.
```

But in the Data validation section, I see this

```
Data validation for table MY_TABLE: 5 FAIL
```

Why does it say it failed? And is the number 5 the number of missing rows or some other error number?